Laravel API data not printed in Vue Js SPA
developing a project using Laravel backend and Vue Js 3 Single page Application
Laravel api is working properly but in the vue js frontend not printing data properly. I have following EmployeeList.vue
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Birth Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Gender</th>
                    <th scope="col">Hire Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody v-for="employee in employees" :key="employee.emp_no">
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.emp_no }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.first_name }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.last_name }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.birth_date }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.gender }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.hire_date }}</th>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        name:'EmployeeList',
        data() {
            return {
                employees:Array
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getEmployees();
        },
        methods:{
            async getEmployees() {
                let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees';
                await axios.get(url).then(response => {
                    this.employees = response.data.employees;
                    console.log(this.employees);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Employee List Component Mounted');
        }
    }
</script>

Edit
I have following Entity Relationships with each Models
Employee.php
class Employee extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['birth_date','first_name','last_name','gender','hire_date'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'emp_no';

    public function titles(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'emp_no','emp_no');
    }

    public function salaries(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no','emp_no');
    }
}

Salary.php
class Salary extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['salary','from_date','to_date'];

    public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
}

Title.php
class Title extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;


    protected $fillable = ['title','from_date','to_date'];


    public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
}

in my browser console EmployeeList Array printing properly. but Vue devtools EmployeeList is empty Array in the vue js html code not displaying EmployeeList data on the browser. what is the problem here? are those relationship effected for this problem?

Should it be employees: [] in the data? Also, if you see it in your network tab + console.log properly, then it should be good. Maybe there is one extra level in the response, like you need to do response.data.employees.data or something. Consider not mixing async/await and .then too. Use your Vue devtools to inspect it more and maybe wrap your result into a <pre>{{ employees }}</pre> to inspect it further. Also consider having <tr class="table-secondary" v-if="employees.length"> to wait until you have received the data. Finally, check for any errors in your browser console

@kissu yes it is printing properly EmployeeList Array on console. but not in web browser

Please consider all the rest of my previous comment then.

difficult to find error. I am panic

Please follow my first comment to get ways of troubleshooting your issue.

Can you try this.employees.push(response.data.employees) instead of replacing this.employees inside async getEmployees()?

@parapente this code got errors here
